# SQL query error with python manage.py migrate with mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am receiving  SQL error `1064 : You have an error in your SQL syntax` when I run `python manage.py migrate`. I am just following the documents and have not even yet created an app, forget about writing any code. All I have done is setting up `settings.py` for mysql as per the documents. There is no error here else I would have a got a database connection error.

My set-up is as follows :
Windows 8, `django 1.8.6`, `mysqlconnector 2.1.3`, installed `mysqlclient` as well, `mysql 5.7.9`, `Python 3`

I have been able to write a complete app on ubuntu where I have `python 2.7`

The complete stack trace is as follows :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064 ....)
```

I have cross checked my settings.py file and everything. In fact the connection is established and sometimes it successfully creates tables`django_content_type` and `django_migrations` and then gives this error and sometimes without creating these tables itself I get this error.

The stack trace printed ends as follows :

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")
```

I have also referred and tried to follow the instructions (installed mysql-connector-python-2.1.3) in other similar queries at this site, but nothing seems to be working

The complete stack trace is as follows :

```
D:\pythonLearn\learningDjango\mysite>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 124, in execute return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 207, in execute self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 37, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorvalue
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 192, in execute r = self._query(query)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 356, in _query rowcount = self._do_query(q)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-md64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 320, in _do_query db.query(q)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 346, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 445, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 93, in handle executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 19, in __init__self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 47, in __init__self.build_graph()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 188, in build_graph   self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations self.ensure_schema()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 53, in ensure_schema editor.create_model(self.Migration)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 289, in create_model self.deferred_sql.extend(self._model_indexes_sql(model))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\schema.py", line 56, in _model_indexes_sql self.connection.cursor(), model._meta.db_table
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\introspection.py", line 142, in get_storage_engine
"WHERE table_name = %s", [table_name])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in __exit__ six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 658, in reraise raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 124, in execute return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 207, in execute self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 37, in defaulterrorhandler raise errorvalue
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 192, in execute r = self._query(query)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 356, in _query rowcount = self._do_query(q)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.4-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 320, in _do_query db.query(q)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1")
```

My `settings.py` has been modified to contain :

```
 DATABASES = { 
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'polldb',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'passwd',
        'HOST' : 'localhost', } }
```

Comment: ya, error in your mysql query..

Comment: Please add the full error traceback and the migration file causing the error to your post by editing it!

Comment: @Klaus D I have added the complete stack trace to the question. I did not understand what do you mean by migration file

Comment: I guess we will need a copy of your model as well.

Comment: @Klaus D not even created a model yet, the documents say that even before you create any app you can perform migrate to see that all is fine

Comment: MySQLdb is not compatible with Python 3. You'll need to use  [mysql-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) or Oracle's own [mysqlconnector-python](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/).

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I have installed both of these.Still no success

Comment: That doesn't help. How did you configure them? What error do you get now?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I configured both using `pip install mysqlclient` and `pip install https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.tar.gz`. The stack trace I have already pasted in the question details

Comment: But did you change your Django configuration to actually use them?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman how is that to be done. I will edit the question to show the `settings.py` file

Comment: Did you uninstall MySQLdb before installing mysql-client? You must only have one of these installed. For mysqlconnector-python, you need to set the `ENGINE` to the one provided by mysqlconnector-python: `'mysql.connector.django'`.